# Consider the Fredholm equation of second kind where K satisfies a Lipschitz condition...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lipschitz-functions

Prove that there exists a unique solution for all $|\lambda|$ $\lt$ $\frac{1} {M(b-a)}$

Where $f(x)=\phi(x)+ \lambda  \int_{a}^{b}K(x,y;f(y)) dy$

And K satisfies a Lipschitz condition of the form $|K(x,y;r)-K(x,y;s)|\le M|r-s|$

And moreover what would the successive approximations to this solution be given by?

I have spent all day researching and attempting to do this however I am stumped.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Banach space $(C[a,b], ||*||)$, where $||*||$ is the $\sup$ -norm and let $T:C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ be defined by

$(Tf)(x)=\phi(x)+ \lambda  \int_{a}^{b}K(x,y;f(y)) dy$.

Its your turm to show, that

$||Tf-Tg|| \le \lambda M (b-a) ||f-g||$ for all $f,g \in C[a,b]$.

Hence, if $\frac{1} {M(b-a)}$, Banach's fix point theorem applies !

Comment: Ummm I will look into this, thankyou and uniquness would follow from the fixed point thm?

Comment: I am not sure if i follow 100% actually could you be more clear?

Comment: nvrm got it, thanks

Comment: Hi Rick,Do you have the detailed solution (or paper) to this problem? I am stumped as well. Thanks.